# Error in d[-MARGIN] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, neural-network

I am new using r. I am trying to fit neural network with a random dataset with 3 different variable (X1, X2, & X3)

```
library(scatterplot3d)
set.seed(1234567890)
nObs <- 1000
ctrPos <- 3
xyzTmp <- matrix(rnorm(3*nObs),ncol=3)
xyzCtrsTmp <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1)*ctrPos,nObs*3,replace=TRUE),ncol=3)
xyzwidthTmp <- matrix(sample(c(-1,1)*ctrPos,nObs*3,replace=TRUE),ncol=3)
xyzTmp <- xyzTmp + xyzCtrsTmp + xyzwidthTmp 
gTmp <- paste0("class",(2+sign(apply(xyzCtrsTmp,xyzwidthTmp,prod)))/2)
data <- data.frame(xyzTmp,xyzCtrsTmp,xyzwidthTmp)
spl <- scatterplot3d(data,pch=12,highlight.3d=TRUE)

nnRes <- neuralnet(g~X1+X2+X3,data.frame(g=as.numeric(factor(gTmp)),xyTmp))
plot(nnRes)
```

I got an error code:

**Error in d[-MARGIN] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts**

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: The line `apply(xyzCtrsTmp,xyzwidthTmp,prod)` gives this error. I do not know what you are trying to do but it may be worth looking at the examples in `?apply` to see how you would normally use that function

Comment: Thank you user20650, You have pointed me in the right direction, I will look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have this matrix `m`.

```
m
#            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
# [1,]  1.3709584  0.6328626  1.51152200
# [2,] -0.5646982  0.4042683 -0.09465904
# [3,]  0.3631284 -0.1061245  2.01842371
```

We can display first column with `1`,

```
m[,1]
# [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284
```

exclude it with `-1`,

```
m[,-1]
#            [,1]        [,2]
# [1,]  0.6328626  1.51152200
# [2,]  0.4042683 -0.09465904
# [3,] -0.1061245  2.01842371
```

display the "zero" column,

```
m[,0]  ## not sure if this is equal to m[,NULL]
# [1,]
# [2,]
# [3,]
```

combine both (which gives the same as `m[,-1]`),

```
m[,c(-1, 0)]
#            [,1]        [,2]
# [1,]  0.6328626  1.51152200
# [2,]  0.4042683 -0.09465904
# [3,] -0.1061245  2.01842371
```

but we cannot combine including and excluding.

```
m[,c(-1, 1)]
# Error in m[, c(-1, 1)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

May this little medidation help to debug your code!

---

*Data*

```
set.seed(42);m <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)
```